# Distributed systems with large number of different types of jobs

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

I want to create a distributed system that can support around 10,000 different types of jobs. One single machine can host only 500 such jobs, as each job needs some data to be pre-loaded into memory, which can't be kept in a cache. Each job must have redundancy for availability.

I had explored open-source libraries like zookeeper, hadoop, but none solves my problem.
The easiest solution that I can think of, is to maintain a map of job type, with its hosted machine. But how can I support dynamic allocation of job type on my fleet? How to handle machine failures, to make sure that each job type must be available on atleast 1 machine, at any point of time.

Comment: Are the jobs predefined? or they come dynamically?

Comment: The jobs would be predefined.

Comment: and is it a batch system or not?

Comment: No, its a realtime system.

Comment: I mean, do you receive some request from users? and based on the request you start a job on one of the machines, right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers that you mentioned in the comments, I propose you to go for a MQ-based (Message Queue) architecture. What I propose in this answer is to:

1. Get the input from users and push them into a distributed message queue. It means that you should set up a message queue (Such as [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)) on several servers. This MQ technology, helps you to replicate the input requests for fault tolerance issues. It also provides a full end-to-end asynchronous system.
2. After preparing this MQ layer, you can setup you computing servers layers. This means that some computing servers (~20 servers in your case) will read the requests from the message queue and start a job based on the request. Because this MQ is distributed, you can make sure that a good level of load balancing can happen in your computing servers. In addition, each server is capable of running as much as jobs that you want (~500 in your case) based on the requests that it reads from the MQ.
3. Regarding the failures, the computing servers may only pop from the MQ, if and only if the job is completed. If one server is crashing, the job is still in the MQ and another server can work on it. If the job is saving some state somewhere or updates something, you should manage its duplicate run then.

The good point about this approach is that it is very salable. It means that if in future you have more jobs to handle, by adding a computing server and connecting it to the MQ, you can process more requests on the servers without any change to the system. In addition, some nice features in the MQ like priority-based queuing, helps you to prioritize the requests and process them based on the job type.

**p.s.** Your Q does not provide any details about the type and parameters of the system. This is a draft solution that I can propose. If you provide more details, maybe the community can help you more.